# Excel Macro that will simply apply a formula to one column

Tags: vba, excel, macros, formula

I know nothing of VBA syntax, and I am needing to create an Excel macro that will simply apply a formula to all populated cells in column A. (Formula being =concatenate(B1,C1,D1) relative to the cell)

I have searched for an answer to this, and while there are many similar questions, they are all very specific and I am unable to manipulate the code given so that it will do this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you tried recording a macro and edit the code ?

Comment: I thing you don't need macro to simple place a formula in the cells of column, just drag it till cell you need the formula

Comment: It is for people who are even less computer savvy than I, and I am trying to automate the process as much as possible for them. This workbook is serving to check their work and this sheet is part of a system. Thank you for your input but yes, I would like to create a macro for this. Also, I have tried recording but I do not seem to get usable code from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bit of code I wrote using a Do While loop to concatenate three separate columns, you could do the same with however many you need with minimal adjustments.

It will laterally concatenate across cells of the same row from information in each designated column and will loop until each row is complete.

```
Dim noSep As String
noSep = ""

Cells(1, 2) = columnOne
Cells(1, 6) = columnTwo
Cells(1, 8) = columnThree
Cells(1, 47) = concatResult

x = 2
Do While Cells(x, columnOne) <> ""
Cells(x, concatResult) = Cells(x, columnOne) & noSep & Cells(x, columnTwo) & noSep & Cells(x, columnThree)
x = x + 1
Loop
```